# Spark-shell error on windows "Illegal character in path at index 32"

Tags: windows, apache-spark

I am trying to setup spark on my new windows laptop. I am getting below error while running spark-shell :

"
ERROR Main: Failed to initialize Spark session.
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 32: spark://DESKTOP-RCMDGS4:49985/C:\classes"

I am using below s/w :
Spark 3.2.1
Java 11
Hadoop: winutils

I have set below environment variables :
HADOOP_HOME, SPARK_HOME, JAVA_HOME, PATH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is known issue in latest spark version. Downgrade to 3.0.3 could fix the issue.

Comment: I also tried 3.1.2 and had the same issue, so as Warren Zhu said, its 3.0.3 which works. Does anyone know if this will be fixed at some point? Or where to raise a bug report?